# Iterated lens leads to 'ambiguous tree iteration'

Tags: augeas

While writing a lens for [Deckard](https://gitlab.labs.nic.cz/knot/deckard) tests I ran into a problem.

This lens

```
let eol = ws . ((del /[;#]/ ";" . [label "#comment" . store /[^\n]*/] 
          . del_str "\n") | (del_str "\n"))* . del_str "\n"
```

results in this error:

```
$ augparse /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/deckard.aug
Syntax error in lens definition
/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/deckard.aug:22.0-.119:Failed to compile eol
/usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/deckard.aug:22.15-.104:exception: ambiguous tree iteration
  Iterated regexp: /     { /#comment/ = /[^\001-\004\n]*/ }
  | ()/
  ' { "#comment" }' can be split into
  '|=| { "#comment" }'

 and
  ' { "#comment" }|=|'

Iterated lens: /usr/share/augeas/lenses/dist/deckard.aug:22.15-.102:
```

I can't get my head around the notation of Augeas' `tree -> plaintext` exception notation so I have no idea what is `augparse` trying to say.

Can anyone help me with an explanation or fix for the lens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Augeas is trying to say here is the following: it was trying to match a tree to this pattern

```
/{ /#comment/ = /[^\001-\004\n]*/ } | ()/
```

For the `tree -> text` direction, Augeas talks about how it matches tree nodes. That notation uses `{ LABEL_RX = VALUE_RX }` to indicate that it tries to match a tree node whose label matches `LABEL_RX` and whose value matches `VALUE_RX` — the children of a tree node are never used for matching. The first part of the above pattern (before the `|`) matches a tree node whose label is `#comment` and whose value matches `[^\001-\004\n]*`. (The `\001-\004` is in there for internal reasons, and Augeas 1.9 will suppress them) The second part matches `()`, Augeas' way to say 'nothing'.

The fact that it talks about iteration means that it found the above construct in an iteration, i.e. something that has a `*` after it.

What it is having trouble with is that if it sees a tree node `{ "#comment" }`: it can't decide whether it should first match the `()` nothing part and then the `#comment` part or vice versa. Since matching the nothing part can cause things to be put into the output (in this case, the `\n` from the `del_str` lens), Augeas throws its hands up and complains about it.

One way out of this is to modify the lens like this:

```
let eol = ws . 
        (del /[;#]/ ";" . [label "#comment" . store /[^\n]*/] . del_str "\n")* .
        del_str "\n"
```

This gets rid of the 'ambiguous tree iteration', at the price that empty lines also create `#comment` nodes (without values) in the tree. But that's probably acceptable.

Comment: This was very informative even though we figured it out before the answer. Thanks a lot.